# Probem with the Tuple type

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, tuples

recently I try to follow the ProAngular by Adam Freeman and I've encountered a problem that I cannot find elsewhere. I have a code:

```
canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state:RouterStateSnapshot)
:Promise<boolean>|boolean{
    if (route.params['mode']=='create') {
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) =>  {
            let responses:[[string, (string) => void]] = [
            ['Tak', () => {resolve(true)}],
            ['Nie', () => {
                this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.url);
                resolve(false);
                }]
            ];
            this.messages.reportMessage(new Message('Akceptujesz warunki?', false, responses));

        });
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
```

Here's a constructor to the class responsible for the message.

```
export class Message{
constructor(private text:string, private error:boolean = false,
                private responses?:[[string, (string) => void]]){

}
```

}

Everything seems OK, but I am receiving an error:

```
error TS2322: Type '[[string, () => void], [string, () => void]]' is not assignable to type '[[string, (string: any) => void]]'.
Types of property 'length' are incompatible.
Type '2' is not assignable to type '1'.
```

It's strange as my code is the same as the one in the book. I know it's something small but I really don't know how to figure this out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

> Types of property 'length' are incompatible.
>   Type '2' is not assignable to type '1'.

```
let responses:[[string, (string) => void]]
```

Declares an array type of exactly one tuple. If you try to initialise it with anything other than one element, it will error.

You need to **change** your `responses` declaration **to**:

```
let responses: [string, (string) => void][]
```

or

```
let responses: Array<[string, (string) => void]>
```

Comment: I've tried this solution, problem still exist even with this clarification. It's related to the size of the 'array' as 2 items are in the responses.

Comment: Try adding `let responses: Array<[string, () => void]>` or `[string, () => void][]` as your array type. Your current type declaration means an array with one and only `tuple`

Comment: There is no problem with the ReportMessage function, but with the declaration of the variable.

Comment: My above comment addresses only your `responses` declaration and not your `ReportMessage` function.

Comment: @ethane answer is right, if change type to "[string, (string) => void][]" code is compiled well